# Constraint on eigenvalues from matrix equations

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given two 2 x 2 complex matrices $A$ and $B$ (not necessarily diagonalizable) such that they satisfy $$A^\dagger A+B^\dagger B=I.$$ is it possible to constrain the eigenvalues of matrices $A$ and $B$ using the above equality? Can someone give me some hints on how to do it? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by constrain? The equation you have is equivalent to saying that the row spaces of $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal, so you can say $rank(A) + rank(B) = 2$, and so there are two possibilities: (i) exactly one of $A$ and $B$ is identically zero, and thus zero eigenvalues, and the other can have any eigenvalue, (ii) $A$ and $B$ each has a single zero eigenvalue, and their other eigenvalues can be anything.

Comment: @karakusc I don't know how you concluded that the row-spaces are orthogonal.  What about $A = B = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}I$?

Comment: Ok, I think I got confused by notation. I interpreted $A^\dagger$ as pseudo-inverse.

Comment: @Rajath I assumed that $\dagger$ refers to the conjugate-transpose.  Please confirm whether this is what you meant.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, in my question $\dagger$ refers to conjugate transpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too much can be said about the eigenvalues directly, but you can certainly get an upper bound.  In particular: we note that for any vector $x$, we have
$$
\|x\|^2 = x^\dagger(A^\dagger A + B^\dagger B)x = x^\dagger A^\dagger A x + x^\dagger B^\dagger Bx = \|Ax\|^2 + \|Bx\|^2
$$
So, we can conclude that for all vectors $x$, we have $\|Ax\| \leq \|x\|$ and $\|Bx\| \leq \|x\|$.  So, any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ or $B$ must satisfy $|\lambda| \leq 1$.

Another notable property is that $\|Ax\| = \|x\| \iff \|Bx\| = 0$ (and symmetrically $\|Bx\| = \|x\| \iff \|Ax\| = 0$).

---

About $A^\dagger B$: using the spectral *norm*, we have
$$
\|A^\dagger B\| \leq \|A^\dagger\| \cdot \|B\| \leq 1
$$
which means that the absolute value of the eigenvalues of $A^\dagger B$ are at most $1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would like to ask the following follow up question. Given the above result can I conclude that the absolute values of eigenvalues of $A^\dagger B$ is also less than one. (using the fact that $\rho(AB)\leq \rho(A)\rho(B)$ where $\rho(A)$ gives the spectral radius of A)?

Comment: Your statement about the spectral radius is not generally true.  However, I do think that we can constrain the eigenvalues of $A^\dagger B$ in this case

Comment: I realized that that statement about spectral radius is true only for commuting matrices Thank you for your answer. It was very helpful.

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR it's also true for pairs of normal matrices (whether or not they commute) because for normal matrices, the spectral radius and spectral norm coincide.

Comment: Also, in the new edit to the answer that you made, did you mean to write '...which means that the absolute value of eigenvalues of $A^\dagger B$ is at most 1'?

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}{}$